# Astro internationalization

Tags: i18next, astrojs

Is there a way to detect the parent folder name to know the current language?

```
src
└── pages
    ├── fr <-- THIS IS THE PARENT FOLDER
    |   └── index.astro 
    └── index.astro
```

Things I tried:

- The integration provided by Astro integration – > not stable yet
- Define a variable for every page and pass it as props to every child component – > very tedious
- Creating a global variable outside pages and changing it inside every page – > didn't work in development mode

I want to access the language from a child component as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is by looking at `Astro.url` in your page or component:

```
---
// The pathname of the current page, e.g. '/fr/'.
const { pathname } = Astro.url;

// The language (parent folder name) will be the second
// item if we split the path at every forward slash.
const lang = pathname.split('/')[1];
---

<p>Language is {lang}.</p>
```

Comment: I thought of it yesterday and it was a good solution but I wanted some approach same to what i18next did